# Stop Script on Null Value in GSheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send a verification email on status change, I can get it to send based on the column content, but I can't make it stop once it sees a null value.  It puts in the email confirmation tag regardless. I need to know how to make it stop on null if the cell in column G is blank.
[Screenshot of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53NH1.png)

```
var CONFIRMATION_SENT = "CONFIRMATION_SENT";

function sendConfirmation(e){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:range
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange ();
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2];
    var completeMessage = "All set!  The accoutn associate with " + emailAddress + " has been deactivated"; // Confrim account is deactive
    var cancelMessage = "Per your request, the account associated with " + emailAddress + " has NOT been deactivated."; // Request cancelled
    var invalidMessage = "The email address of " + emailAddress + " is not accociated with a brightwheel account."; // Invalid email
    var confirmationSent = row[7];
    var status = row[6];
     var subject = "Brightwheel Deactivation Request For - " + emailAddress;
    if (confirmationSent != CONFIRMATION_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      if (status != null) {return;}
      else{
      if (status = "Complete - Account Deactivated") {MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, completeMessage);}
      if (status = "Request Canceled - Account Still Active") {MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, cancelMessage);}
      if (status = "Not a Valid Email - Account Not Found") {MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, invalidMessage);}
      }
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue(CONFIRMATION_SENT); //Cell = index array + 1
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try replacing this:**

```
if (status != null) {return;}
      else{
      if (status = "Complete - Account Deactivated") {MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, completeMessage);}
      if (status = "Request Canceled - Account Still Active") {MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, cancelMessage);}
      if (status = "Not a Valid Email - Account Not Found") {MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, invalidMessage);}
      }
```

**with this:**

```
 switch(data[i][6])
  {
    case 'Complete - Account Deactivated':
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, completeMessage);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue(CONFIRMATION_SENT);
      break;
    case 'Request Canceled - Account Still Active':
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, cancelMessage);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue(CONFIRMATION_SENT);
      break;
    case 'Not a Valid Email - Account Not Found':
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, invalidMessage);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue(CONFIRMATION_SENT);
      break;
    default:
      break;//We don't want to return here we want to break so that we can continue on to any remain lines.
  }
```

I was looking at your code and noticed that I should have probably included setting the column that prevents duplicate emails.

**This works:**

I just tested it.

```
function sendConfirmation()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange ();
  var data=rg.getValues();
  var s=''
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) 
  {
    var completeMessage = "All set!  The accoutn associate with " + data[i][2] + " has been deactivated";
    var cancelMessage = "Per your request, the account associated with " + data[i][2] + " has NOT been deactivated.";
    var invalidMessage = "The email address of " + data[i][2] + " is not accociated with a brightwheel account.";
    var subject = "Brightwheel Deactivation Request For - " + data[i][2];
    if (!data[i][7]) 
    { 
      switch(data[i][6])
      {
        case 'Status1':
          MailApp.sendEmail(data[i][2], subject, completeMessage);
          //s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />i: %s email: %s subject: %s message: %s',i,data[i][2], subject, completeMessage);
          sh.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue('CONFIRMATION_SENT');
          break;
        case 'Status2':
          MailApp.sendEmail(data[i][2], subject, cancelMessage);
          //s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />i: %s email: %s subject: %s message: %s',i,data[i][2], subject, cancelMessage);
          sh.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue('CONFIRMATION_SENT');
          break;
        case 'Status3':
          MailApp.sendEmail(data[i][2], subject, invalidMessage);
          //s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />i %s email: %s subject: %s message: %s',i,data[i][2], subject, invalidMessage);
          sh.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue('CONFIRMATION_SENT');
          break;
        default:
          break;//Dont return just break and go on to next line.
      }
    }
  }
  //var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Emails Sent');
}
```

The big problem was the return.  That just stopped the script in it's tracks.  We just a break in there so we could go on to the next line.  I left my debug stuff in there and I simplified some of the status statements for my convenience during debugging.

**This is what my spreadsheet looks like:**

[image]

**This is my debug screen:**

[image]

Comment: This works^, but only if I go in order from top to bottom.  If I want to confirm line three, while leaving line 2 unconfined, the script does not run.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what your talking about.

Comment: If you look at row 5 in this screenshot, I did not choose a status, I did choose a status in row 6 though and the script did not run. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93AQxHg8KKnOXY1aUF6SEVUWTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay it seems to be working.  The big problem was the return.  We just needs a break  in the switch statement.